# Adjust html table row length so that entire cell text is shown

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a table that displays text fetched from an API using JS and because of that a lot of my cells have different length. I've been trying to create a table with a vertical and horizontal scroll, which I managed to do but I can't seem to figure out how to adjust table row length so that entire text is shown, instead of being cut out. I would like for a cell to have a maximum length and if that length is exceeded the text is shown on the next line. This might not be doable with css only but any solution is welcomed.

[Here is a quick look on my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3km6.png)

Here is part of my CSS for the Match History Table

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.table2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 450px;
    left: 400px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 1001px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: block;
}

.table2 tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 300px;
}
.table2 td, th {
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    border: dashed 1px lightblue;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Some conflicting terms here - so little unclear - could you provide a simulated "ater" image?

Comment: Sounds like you want `.td { white-space: normal }` and remove the `td` `text-overflow:ellipses` and `overflow:hidden`

Comment: Just noticed: above should say **after image**

Answer (score 0):

**1st part** of your issue is some cells needing longer lengths than others, so you could set the colspan for those longer than the others.

**2nd part** is by setting a max-width on those columns you can program how they behave when text is too long for the cells width.  If you already know which column's cells will need more room, try adding a larger max width for those cells which will affect all cells in that column.

```
td:nth-child(1) {
   width: 100px
}

td:nth-child(2) {
   max-width: 400px; /* Comment this line to see the width stretch based on cell's 
   content */
}
```

I have included a working example of how you should set colspan and a modified version of your CSS here: https://codepen.io/TxsAdamWest/pen/NWbOwRW

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my issue by adding a class with a min-width attribute to the headers that needed their length adjusted and as for the body, since it is generated dynamically using JS I did the same thing using cell.style.minWidth to a specific row.